# Adding sites with unique ip via cpanel

Tags: ip-address, cpanel

I have 10 sites currently on my server with cpanel. Currently they are all add on domains under the same account, however I want to assign a unique ip address for each site. Is it possible to keep the same setup where the domains are under the same account and be able to assign a unique ip to each site?

If not and I have to create seperate cpanel accounts for each ip/domain can I still have all domains point to the same directory? All 10 domains point to the same directory, its a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, you edit the apache file for each domain specifically.